# Projecting points onto an existing mesh, and creating cut outs centered on those points

Tags: modeling, mesh

[image][image]I have model of a head- with a triangular mesh. I then upload the mesh to blender and create a wireframe mesh. I want to project a set of points onto the surface of this mesh (1) and then create cut outs centered around these points (2). I have looked up projecting geometry in blender but I am not sure that is what I am looking for because I am not projecting onto a face but rather around the whole head. Essentially I would like to combine preset- points into an existing mesh and create cut outs in those spots. I am so new to blender I am not sure where else to look.

UPDATE: I have uploaded a picture, I would like to somehow project the geometry on the right onto the surface of the left mesh, and create cut outs centered at the vertices(from the right, that are now on the left).

Comment: pls add images (best one before, one after) how it was and how it should look like. There is often a lot of room for interpretation if you just describe this by words.

Comment: Hi, Ashlyn, and welcome .. What @Chris said.  :)  There's more ambiguity in this question than you might think.  Some kind of illustration of what _sort_ of 'set of points'  and what _sort_ of 'cut-outs' , is absolutely necessary, here, before anyone can give you a definite answer.

Comment: I provided an update, thank you for replying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your wording is still a bit vague, details of the method could vary wildly depending on the particulars of your goals, but here's a `Solidify` + `Geometry Nodes` setup that fits the general sense of what you've described. It takes in a (wireframe) object, moves (`Set Position`) its vertices to the closest positions (`Geometry Proximity`) on the main object, then places an object on each of them (`Instance on Points`), aligning their *Z* axes to the nearest face *normal*. Finally, it cuts these instanced copies from the main mesh (`Mesh Boolean`). You can choose which objects to use as wireframe or cutter from the dropdown menus in the modifier panel:

[image]

`Mesh Boolean` inside *Geometry Nodes* is a really slow operation, so if you wanna manipulate your wireframe mesh I'd suggest disabling the modifier while doing so. You could do the cutting outside of Geometry Nodes using a `Boolean` modifier in *Fast* mode to help with performance, but that has its own drawbacks, it would depend on your project's needs. Feel free to ask further questions if you'd be interested about that method, or you're lost about the setup I've shown since you're new to Blender.

[image]

Comment: I attempted the workflow using the geometry nodes modifier but it is not working. Since I am new I am assuming I am doing something wrong, I will attach another picture.

Comment: @AshlynMcCann It might be because where they're placed in 3D (the "Relative" mode) and their origin points (the "Original" mode). Can you right click on the two blobs > Set Origin > Origin to Geometry (place their origin points in the middle of their mesh), and then set both of them to Original mode in Geometry Nodes and see if that works?

Comment: okay so that is working much better, thank you. One problem I am facing now is that scaling the cylinder to be larger does not change the size of the cut outs, how can I adjust this?

Comment: also, the cylinders are projecting not from the circular face but rather  along the length of the cylinder

Comment: @AshlynMcCann They don't get bigger probably because you're not 'applying' your scale (Ctrl+A>Scale) so GN is using their original size. Either apply scale, or scale them using the values you see on the `Instance on Points` node. To orient them right, try the other two axes on the `Align Euler` node